# How to write df as parquet to s3 in polars rust?

Tags: amazon-s3, rust, rust-polars

I am a bit out of ideas as after doing this

```
let mut cursor = Cursor::new(Vec::new());
let parquet_bytes = ParquetWriter::new(cursor)
    .with_statistics(true)
    .with_compression(ParquetCompression::Snappy)
    .finish(df)
    .unwrap();
```

I no longer own cursor to pass to s3 sdk.  is there a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing cursor as a mutable reference? Something like this:

```rust
    let s3_client = aws_sdk_s3::Client::new();

    let mut df = df!("a" => &[1,2]).unwrap();
    let mut buf = vec![];
   
    ParquetWriter::new(&mut buf).finish(&mut df).unwrap();

    s3_client
        .put_object()
        .bucket("my-bucket-data")
        .key("tmp.parquet")
        .body(buf.into())
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap();
```

Comment: since this write to an in-mem buffer and then spills to the object store, would this be the most performant way to do writes ?

Comment: I'm not aware of alternatives for Polar DF -> AWS S3 parquet

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [object_store](https://docs.rs/object_store/latest/object_store/) crate in combination with polars as follows:

```rs
use object_store::aws::AmazonS3Builder;
use object_store::path::Path;
use polars::io::parquet::ParquetWriter;
use polars::{io::cloud::CloudWriter, prelude::*};

fn main() -> Result<(), PolarsError> {
    let object_store = AmazonS3Builder::from_env()
        .with_bucket_name("holapolars")
        .build()?;

    let mut s = DataFrame::new(vec![
        Series::new("names", &["a", "b", "c"]),
        Series::new("values", &[1, 2, 3]),
    ])?;

    let cloud_writer =
        CloudWriter::new_with_object_store(Arc::from(object_store), Path::from("example.parquet"))
            .unwrap();
    ParquetWriter::new(cloud_writer).finish(&mut s).unwrap();

    Ok(())
}
```

This snippet expects the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` credentials to be available as environment variables.